# How do I make my Maven Docker image look for it's dependencies/parent in Nexus?

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile, nexus, parent-pom

I'm trying to use a Maven Docker image to build a project. The pom of the project has it's parent in a Nexus repository. When I build the project, it says that the parent pom is not resolvable since it doesn't look for it in Nexus. How do I make the image look in Nexus? I am able to build the same project locally on my machine using the Maven installation.

This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-amazoncorretto-11
COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/
CMD ["mvn","-v"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put a section in your settings file telling it where the nexus repo is. This is done with the servers and mirrors sections and can also be repeated in individual poms if you wish to override it.

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>nexus-releases</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>central</name>
      <url>http://your-host:8081/repository/maven-group/</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>

</settings>
```

This example is taken from [a sonatype blog entry](https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-1-maven-artifacts) from a couple of years ago, but I think it still works.